# Nodejs Firebase cloud messaging delayed delivery on android

Tags: android, node.js, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to push some high-priority data messages from a nodejs backend to the android client. Here is my code,

```
var payload = {
        data
      };

var options = {
        priority: "high",
        timeToLive: 0,
        ttl: 0,
        android: {
          priority: "high",
          timeToLive: 0,
          ttl: 0,
        },
      };

   admin.messaging()
        .sendToDevice(deviceFcmId, payload, options)
        .then(function (response) {})
        .catch(function (response) {
          console.error("error sendNotification", response);
        });
```

As you can see, I'm using `priority "high"` and `timeToLive: 0`. But this does not wake up the device if it is in `Doze` mode, or sometimes even if the device is in an unlocked state, the message is delayed up to a few minutes. This is a voice-calling app, so the delivery delay should be minimal. I've searched similar posts on StackOverflow but nothing works for me. What am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
In my app, there are two types of notifications, Chat notifications and Call notifications. When the user receives a chat notification, the app will write a `Realm` database entry and fetch the sender's profile picture from API, and shows the notification. I know it's a network call, but the thing is, the image fetching is managed by `Glide` so 90% of the time it will be a disk cache read rather than a network call (even the network call has a 1-second timeout, after this timeout, it will return a local image).

When the user receives a call notification, the app will start a service and ping the caller using `socket.io`. If the ping is a success it will show the call screen using a fullscreen intent by calling `startForeground` from the service. If the ping fails it will show a miscall notification and stops the service.

So, no matter whichever the case is there will always be a user-facing notification.

Answer (score 1):

From the [official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/message-priority#using_high_priority_messages_for_android)

> High priority messages on Android are meant for time sensitive, user visible content, and should result in user-facing notifications. If FCM detects a pattern in which messages do not result in user-facing notifications, your messages **may be deprioritized** to normal priority. FCM uses 7 days of message behavior when determining whether to deprioritize messages; it makes this determination independently for every instance of your application. If, in response to high priority messages, notifications are displayed in a way that is visible to the user, then your future high-priority messages will not be deprioritized.

This means your android app should pretty much just show a notification (make sure the app has notifications enabled). If you abuse this and instead try to directly do other things when receiving the push (such as open connections to the backend or do any other computationally-expensive task) then your messages might be downgraded to normal priority.

On a single device, you can verify if a message has been deprioritized by checking if `getPriority()` returns a lower value than `getOriginalPriority()`.
And for all messages, you can query the [Data API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery#aggregated_delivery_data_via_the_data_api).

Comment: The app has notifications enabled. Even if it's a normal priority, shouldn't it be able to display the notification immediately when the device is in an unlocked state? Please see the updated question.

Comment: I see you are starting a service in call notifications. That sounds like something that might get you de-prioritized according to the docs. I'd just show the notification and only if the user interacts with it I would start the service if needed.

Comment: A foreground service is required to show the call screen even if the phone is locked. I guess it's common in voice calling apps.

Comment: Yes, but it might get your messages deprioritized if you start it right after receiving the push message. To avoid this you could first show a notification informing the user that he is being called, and then when the user clicks the notification, do all the other things.